# Component start with a lower case ltter

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run my build on visual studio but its says my .razor file starts with a lower case but it doesn't I changed it to an uppercase letter and also double checked my other .razor files and none of them start with a lower case number can some one tell me why?

tried restarting and saving all

Comment: Renaming the File does not automagically rename the class/component/whatever contained. The compiler is probably upset about the latter, not the former.

Comment: nvm it was just some intelisense glitch